# How to redirect to an error page when database connection fails?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

I'm Trying to implement a feature in my application like, On the first request to the container, if the database fails to connect, it should redirect to an error page instead of showing `index.jsp`.

1. I have a singleton `DBConnectionManager` class, which handles the database connection in the constructor also a method to return connection object.
2. I have a servlet Context Listener. So when the context is initialized, it would call the `DBConnectionManager` constructor and initializes the database connection. I will retrieve and use the same connection object in all my model DAO.

Now my problem is how do i handle the connection error and redirect it to `error.jsp` page from `DBConnectionManager` or servlet context listener. Where should i place that condition for redirection.

For Reference:
DBConnectionManager.java=>

```
public DBConnectionManager(String url,String user,String pass)
{
//constructor called by servlet context listener.
this.DBURL=url;
this.user=user;
this.pass=pass;
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
log.info("Class Not Found :"+e);
return;
}
try {
log.info("-------url recieved :"+url);
log.info("-------username received :"+user);
log.info("--------password received :"+pass);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
log.info("con initialised..");
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
//Exception caught here successfully.
log.info("Problem in connecting :"+e);
return;
}

if (con != null) {
log.info("Connected Successfully to database");
} else {
log.info("Mysql not connected.:<");
}

public Connection getConnection()
{
 //Method called in every DAOmodel to return the instance of the connection object.
 //Where DAO uses this connection object to query database.
return this.con;   
}
```

Here comes my Servlet Context Listener=>

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        ServletContext ctx=servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        String url=ctx.getInitParameter("DBURL");
        String user=ctx.getInitParameter("DBUSER");
        String pass=ctx.getInitParameter("DBPWD");

        //Constructor called here
        DBConnectionManager dbManager= new DBConnectionManager(url,user,pass);
        log.info("printing db manager::"+dbManager);
        ctx.setAttribute("DBManager", dbManager);
        log.info("dbmanager Initialized");

        }

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        ServletContext ctx=servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        DBConnectionManager dbManager=      (DBConnectionManager)ctx.getAttribute("DBManager");
        dbManager.closeConnection();
        log.info("dbmanager destroyed and database connection closed");
}
```

Hope this might solve if you have any doubt in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception and define a 500 page for that kind of errors in your `web.xml` like;

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

When your system gives error, `error.html` will be rendered. For other type errors, you can define;

```
<error-page>
    <!-- Missing login -->
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error-401.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error-403.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Uncaught exception -->
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error-500.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Unsupported servlet method -->
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/error-503.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: That would be http error based one. My question is different.

Comment: Your question is also for http based redirection, if exception thwrown while connection, this structure will redirect you error page instead of index.jsp

Comment: If i have a the dbconnection and exception management code in the Servlet(Controller). I could configure my web.xml to redirect to some error page. I have this under model class.

Comment: Ok, you probably use that model in your controllers. If you throw exception on model, it will be cacthed with error page handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want handle all db exception, you need to throw it as a some *SomeDbException* and add it to `web.xml`. Also take a look to following [doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm).

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>SomeDbException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: If a servlet throws some exception, container would look for configurations in web.xml. Here servlet is not involved. DBConnectionManager is a just a java class(Model).

Comment: OK, but DBConnectionManager is called from servlet, is not? So you will throw the exception in `DBConnectionManager` not catch it enywere or catch it and rethrow another exception, and as a result servlet container automatically will redirect it to configured page.

Comment: I'm not calling DBConnectionManager from any servlet. I'm calling it from ServletContextLister.

Comment: So you can handle exception in `ServletContextListener`, add an information to `ServletContext` attribute and in Filter or Servlet read this information. See [here](http://lfhck.com/question/345849/prefered-way-to-handle-java-exceptions-in-servletcontextlistener)

Comment: Yes, but I think it is better do it in `filter` to not merge handling with `servlet` logic.

Comment: If i try to bind that information in servlet context, i can solve it => 1. by getting the servletcontext attribute in jsp and redirecting to error page (Writing some java conditions in jsp which is not preferred in MVC). 2.In all the servlet i should get that context attribute and make a redirection. Also in first case i'm not calling any servlet. But it would work when a request is made to controller (i.e not first but from second and next successive requests to controller). Its overhead.

Comment: Declare one `filter` handling all requests and make checking there. It will be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which kind of error, you can always redirect to any other pages:

```
<%
try {
    // do whatever you want (Connect to database ...)
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // logging ...

    response.sendRedirect(..);
    return;
}
%>
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, But I'm a little bit confuse about your question. But:

- If an error happens at servlet init and your single tone class is in it, just leave this error because Application fail to start, and user should fix it anyway, you can generate log of whatever to help to user to figure out what is the problem!
- For utilities and some special cases Singleton is not bad, but for the web application you should avoid it as much as you can. You can make an instance and put it on session if it's for unique for each user, and if it's unique in entire system, you can put it on servlet Context. getServletContext().setAttribute("my", sample);
  Hope that it help

I hope this may help you

Comment: It is not a servlet class. So i have not used response or request object. It is just a singleton java class. Then how could i use response.sendRedirect();

Answer (score 0):

@Prithviraj: Here is the answer :  Suppose if you are having `Index.jsp` page where connection gets fail and you get some exception.
So in that page (`Index.jsp`), you need to use `errorPage` attribute of `<%@ page %>` directive. Like this : `<%@ page errorPage="Error.jsp %>` 
And in the `Error.jsp` page, you need to use `isErrorPage` attribute of `<%@ page %>` directive.
Like this : `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>`.
Now what will happen when connection gets fail and exception comes then automatically control will be redirected to `Error.jsp` page and you will not have to write the redirection logic.

I believe it will help you.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I need to redirect from index.jsp page to error.jsp page on SQLException. How can i make index.jsp to listen for SQLException.

Comment: You need not to worry about it, if any exception will come then control will redirect to error.jsp page. And on error.jsp page you would be having built-in exception object so for the type of exception you can use exception object.